# Texture transparency of black background in OPENGL

Tags: c++, opengl, background, textures

I'm working with sprite animation (OpenGL + C++). I have some trouble with blending.

I'm trying to load an image with a black background and draw it over another texture without a block of black appearing around the image.

I tried playing with different blending functions. I either end up with a blocky image or a translucent image.
An example to better understand my situation.

[image]

I want it to be:

[image]

Here I upload a little bit of my code:

```
//-----------------------------------------------------------------

t.Create2DTexture(filename);
t.UseTexture(filename);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, t.Create2DTexture(filename));


glBegin(GL_QUADS);
glTexCoord2f(1.0, 0.0);
glVertex2f(0.5, 0.5);
glTexCoord2f(1.0, 1.0);
glVertex2f(0.5, -0.5);
glTexCoord2f(0.0, 1.0);
glVertex2f(-0.5, -0.5);
glTexCoord2f(0.0, 0.0);
glVertex2f(-0.5, 0.5);
glEnd();
glPopMatrix();
```

I have seen in many answers that it can work with shaders and discards but I don't really know how.

Comment: Does the image even have an alpha channel? What is the format of the image? Where do you enable blending? Where do you set the blending function? Are you drawing the object after the objects in the background or is the depth test disabled?

Comment: Are you using some kind of framework? What is `t`? Does it handle alpha-channels properly (if there is any)?

Comment: On another note, why do you call `Create2DTexture` twice? Why do you need to present the filename for both `Create2DTexture` and `UseTexture`? Do you really load the texture twice (or thrice in your specific case)?

Comment: Hi! First of all thank you for answering! About the format of the image is png. I enable blending right before the code I've put using 
 glEnable(GL_BLEND);
 glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

Comment: T is an TextureManager type object. In texture manager i've methods to create textures. And finally I call Create2DTexture twice otherwise the texture doesn't work. I'm sorry that my question is not clear, I'm not used to OpenGL

Comment: Looks like the problem is that `Create2DTexture` doesn't create an alpha channel.